# Function that writes values to the local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working with a school project, and I'm new with this and stuck.... I want to create a function that takes in two arguments. 
The variables should be used to define a local storage object. 
I then need to call the function and pass in a key and a value for each argument respectively. 
This function should write these values out to local storage.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function storage(font, helvetica) {
    var object = localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');

    console.log(object);

    return object;
}
```

Comment: ``localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');`` will return **undefined**, so your variable ``object `` will be **undefined**.

Comment: You can grab the localStorage by doing this : ```myStorage = window.localStorage;``` Also [DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: You are sending the literal "font" and "Helvetica" strings as arguments to `localStorage.setIem`. You need to change that to `localStorage.setItem(font, helvetica)` if you want to use the parameters of the `storage` function.